# Appending text to a existing line in a textfile

Tags: java, file-io

I am seriously stuck in this task trying to figure out how i can append text after the last char on a existing line.

Basically i want to be able to define a `lineNumber` and the `text` i would like to append. I have tried different types of writers and output streams but none of them seem to support this?

Do i really need to recreate the file temporary and rewrite it again with the appended text, which seems very cumbersome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `java.io.RandomAccessFile` - it will treat your file as a large array of bytes. This lets you write to a file in a random access manner. But, unfortunately not delete and insert. This means:

- There's no easy way to position yourself on a given line.
- When you append text to one line, you will overwrite the beginning of the next line.

You don't state your motivation, but other answers on SO indicates that people with similar problems really need a database.

Alternatively, maybe you can read your text file into a data structure that facilitates what you need to do, and write the file back out to disk when you are done.

Answer (score -1):

Please use [LineNumberReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html) class from java.io package It will help your course. It has methods to keep track of line numbers read from a text file, which you can easily combine at the end of your text.
Try this sample code :

```
    LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("e:/abc.txt"));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        int lineNumber = reader.getLineNumber();
        System.out.println(lineNumber + " - " + line);
    }
```

Comment: I am infact using `LineNumberReader`, but it does not solve my appending issue.

Comment: I have added a sample code, please check if it behaves the way you want.

Comment: Ankur, i know how to extract the line etc. But how do i append to that specific line?

Comment: Append to what? Do you mean you need to append line number to the line and write it back to the file ?

Comment: Ankur, as i explained in the first line of a my question, i need to append text to a specific existing line.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26779/discussion-between-ankur-and-javacake)